# Error while running Storm MultiLang using Python

Tags: java, python, apache-storm

I am following a course work on Apache Storm from Udacity. The version of storm being used is **0.9.3**

One of the exercises there is to run a topology which contains a bolt written in Python. Briefly here are the steps followed. For the purpose of this exercise my source directory is `src` and my package is `udacity.storm`

1. Create directory called `resources/` under `udacity/storm`. Place two python scripts there - `splitsentence.py` and `storm.py`.
2. Create a bolt `SplitSentence` under the package `udacity.storm`. `SplitSentence` bolt derives from `ShellBolt` and implements the `IRichBolt` interface.
3. Build the topology using maven. During the process also package the `resources/` directory within the JAR file.
4. Submit the topology to storm using the command `storm jar target/mytopology.jar udacity.storm.MyTopology`.

The topology loads up and dies immediately and I see the following error on the console

> The storm client can only be run from within a release. You appear to
>   be trying to run the client from a checkout of Storm's source code.

I took a look at the **storm.py** code and figured out that this would happen if the `lib/` directory is not present in the directory from where the python script is executing. After putting in some debug statements I identified that the python script runs from the following location :

> /tmp/06380be9-d413-4ae5-b387-fafe3acf3e65/supervisor/stormdist/tweet-word-count-1-1449502750

I navigate to this directory and find that the `lib/` folder is absent.

The [Storm Multilang](http://storm.apache.org/documentation/Using-non-JVM-languages-with-Storm.html) page does not give much information that would be helpful for beginners to debug the problem being faced.

Any help to solve this problem is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Are there any notes on Udacity's forums that someone has encountered this problem before?

Comment: @morganw09dev Thanks for your help. I have posted my finding below which details the cause of the error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the problem after some fair amount of looking around. Actually, the problem is not within the instructions themselves but because the `storm.py` file I had included in my resources directory was of an older or incorrect version - I had obtained the URL via a Google search and probably ended up with an incorrect one.

The `storm.py` to be downloaded is from [this](https://github.com/apache/storm/blob/master/storm-multilang/python/src/main/resources/resources/storm.py) Github link. I am now able to run the exercises successfully.

Thank you all for your help. I will ensure that I post this up in Udacity forums so that people are aware of the confusion.

Comment: Thanks for your help. But I posted the reason for my errors in my answer below.

Answer (score 0):

As the error says you try to run within the source code. Just download the binary release https://storm.apache.org/downloads.html and follow the setup instructions https://storm.apache.org/documentation/Setting-up-a-Storm-cluster.html

Afterwards, you can prepare your `jar` file and submit to the cluster via `bin/storm jar yourJarFile.jar` (see https://storm.apache.org/documentation/Command-line-client.html)

There is no need (as long as you don't want to work on Storm itself) to download the source code manually. Just include the corresponding jar files from the binary release to your project. If you use maven (and only run in local mode), just include the corresponding maven dependency (see https://storm.apache.org/documentation/Maven.html); there is no need to download the binary release manually for this case.

Answer (score 0):

In case anyone else experiences this problem:

I had the same issue. However, I couldn't resolve it by copying storm.py from the binary release to my resources directory.

My initial error was "AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'BasicBolt'"

You can add the correct Maven dependency to your pom.xml which will copy the correct dependencies into your JAR. Add the artifact "multilang-python", groupId "org.apache.storm" with version matching your Storm version, then run the clean and package goals to produce the updated JAR file.